# Object Not found in xampp server in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new to code igniter and i am developing simple login system for that i am using  xampp , i uploaded code igniter in folder code/ and the following are the codes in mvc

controller  login.php

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Login extends CI_Controller
     {

 public function __construct()
 {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->helper('html');
      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      //load the login model
      $this->load->model('login_model');
 }

 public function index()
 {
      //get the posted values
      $username = $this->input->post("txt_username");
      $password = $this->input->post("txt_password");

      //set validations
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_username", "Username", "trim|required");
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password", "Password", "trim|required");

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
           //validation fails
           $this->load->view('login_view');
      }
      else
      {
           //validation succeeds
           if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
           {
                //check if username and password is correct
                $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password);
                if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                {
                     //set the session variables
                     $sessiondata = array(
                          'username' => $username,
                          'loginuser' => TRUE
                     );
                     $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
                     redirect("index");
                }
                else
                {
                     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username and password!</div>');
                     redirect('login/index');
                }
           }
           else
           {
                redirect('login/index');
           }
      }
 }
 }?>
```

MOdel is  login_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class login_model extends CI_Model
      {
   function __construct()
        {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
         }

 //get the username & password from tbl_usrs
   function get_user($usr, $pwd)
    {
        $sql = "select * from tbl_usrs where username = '" . $usr . "' and password = '" . md5($pwd) . "' and status = 'active'";
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      return $query->num_rows();
 }
  }?>
```

And View is login_view

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Login Form</title>
 <!--link the bootstrap css file-->
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <style type="text/css">
 .colbox {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
 }
 </style>
   </head>
           <body>
              <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
           <h1>COLORS</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">

           <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top:20px">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
           </ul>

           </div>
          </div>
       </div>
        <hr/>

              <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 well">
      <?php 
      $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "loginform", "name" => "loginform");
      echo form_open("login/index", $attributes);?>
      <fieldset>
           <legend>Login</legend>
           <div class="form-group">
           <div class="row colbox">
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                <label for="txt_username" class="control-label">Username</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="txt_username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_username'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('txt_username'); ?></span>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
           <div class="row colbox">
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
           <label for="txt_password" class="control-label">Password</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" id="txt_password" name="txt_password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_password'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('txt_password'); ?></span>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input id="btn_login" name="btn_login" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" />
                <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" />
           </div>
           </div>
      </fieldset>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             </div>

          <!--load jQuery library-->
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <!--load bootstrap.js-->
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
      </html>
```

IN config i used
    $config['index_page'] = '';
and in routes i used
    $route['default_controller'] = 'login';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
while accessing localhost/code/ it is working fine but when click login button it is going to url  http://localhost/code/localhost/login/index and showing object not found  ERROR 404

Comment: set your base_url in config file

Comment: i set base url as localhost

Comment: add your project name also

Comment: i added localhost/code but it showing http://localhost/code/localhost/code/login/index object not found and error 404

Comment: Your file and class names should have first letter upper case as per user guide if your using CI3 versions.

Comment: i treid it shownig same problem

Comment: i used same class Login and file as Login.php but it is showing same thing

Comment: Check your htaccess for index.php/login or index.php or just login path

Comment: these are my .htaccess files <IfModule authz_core_module>
    
Require all denied

</IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
 
   Deny from all

</IfModule>

Comment: sorry these are my htaccess file  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open `application/config/config.php` and set your `base_url()`. E.g: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/code/';`

Create `.htaccess` file under `/code` folder (Where application and system folder is) like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it is working but after i enter login deatils [link] http://localhost/code/login/index  showing 404 error

Comment: You have to add all pages (including your POST URL) in your routes.php file. It'll fix this error.

Comment: Open application/config/routes.php and add lines like this:

`$route['some_url'] = 'Controller_name/function_name';`

Edit this sample for your own system.

Answer (score 3):

create `.htaccess` file in \code\

as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /code/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/code';
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error as shown below. I am using **php/codeigniter**. I have defined `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/******';` in my config file. still it was showing same issue.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

How could  I solve this.

Step 1: 1st i checked httpd.conf file. there `mod_rewrite` was imported.

Step 2: checked file is located at actual location or not.

Step 3: checked spelling mistake in redirection or anchor tag.

Step 4: checked `$config['base_url']` variable in *application/config.php* file.

Step 5: checked `$config['index_page']` variable in *application/config.ph* file. here was my actual problem. I set it to blank and there was something wrong with my `mod_rewrite` module. when I put `$config['index_page']='index.php'` it started working for me.